# Why is watcher giving errors?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat, elasticsearch-watcher

I want to send slack notifications to a channel as soon as any log with loglevel ERROR appears in my index. I have configured watcher in the following way but it is giving me errors. The slack message must have the log message.
I am not able to configure this exactly.

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "index-log*",
          "index-beat*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "loglevel": "ERROR"
            },
            "range": {
              "@timestamp": {
                "from": "{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}||-5m",
                "to": "{{ctx.trigger.triggered_time}}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gt": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "send_trigger": {
      "webhook": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "hooks.slack.com",
        "port": 443,
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/services/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX",
        "params": {},
        "headers": {
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": """{ "text": "{{ctx.payload}}"}"""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

below is the structure of my logs in kibana

```
{
  "_index": "index-beat",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "P3Toa34B1LVeuWotaVOY",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2022-01-18T06:38:19.559Z",
    "name": "communication",
    "loglevel": "ERROR",
    "log": {
      "file": {
        "path": "/home/ubuntu/abc/abc/logs/communication.log"
      },
      "offset": 0
    },
    "timestamp": "2022-01-18T06:38:15.384279",
    "exception": {
      "ex_type": "None",
      "ex": "None",
      "tb": ""
    },
    "message": "{'err': 'Test'}"
  },
  "fields": {
    "exception.ex_type": [
      "None"
    ],
    "loglevel.keyword": [
      "ERROR"
    ],
    "name.keyword": [
      "communication"
    ],
    "log.offset": [
      0
    ],
    "message": [
      "{'err': 'Test'}"
    ],
    "exception.tb": [
      ""
    ],
    "exception.ex": [
      "None"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-01-18T06:38:19.559Z"
    ],
    "exception.tb.keyword": [
      ""
    ],
    "loglevel": [
      "ERROR"
    ],
    "log.file.path": [
      "/home/ubuntu/abc/abc/logs/communication.log"
    ],
    "message.keyword": [
      "{'err': 'Test'}"
    ],
    "name": [
      "communication"
    ],
    "exception.ex_type.keyword": [
      "None"
    ],
    "exception.ex.keyword": [
      "None"
    ],
    "log.file.path.keyword": [
      "/home/ubuntu/abc/abc/logs/communication.log"
    ],
    "timestamp": [
      "2022-01-18T06:38:15.384Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me out in this one.